# Usage of Parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

How can I make the code below parallel, without locks

```
List l = new List();        
foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
{
    L.Add(Process(item));
}
```

I prefer answers for c# 3.5, but 4.0 will be also ok

Comment: It would help if you made 'returns a value' and 'combine ...' a little more concrete. Such details matter (a lot).

Comment: @Henk, I made some clarifications in the body of the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of taking a sequence of numbers, performing some costly operation on each of them in parallel, and then aggregating the result (not in parallel).

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
int[] squaredNumbers = new int[numbers.Length];
Parallel.For(0, numbers.Length, i => squaredNumbers[i] = (int)Math.Pow(numbers[i], 2));
int sum = squaredNumbers.Sum();
```

Just be careful about thread safety in the operation you perform in the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

> and combine every value output after the loop finished

If we take that literally there is no problem, just store those values in a(nother) array and process/combine them after the loop.

But I suspect you want to combine (add) them during the loop. And then without locking.

The best solution would seem not to use a `Parallel.For()` but a LINQ  `.AsParallel()` solution.

Comment: I don't mind to combine them after the loop is finished, I just want elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Using PLINQ assuming that ordering is important:

```
var result = sourceCollection
  .AsParalle()
  .AsOrdered()
  .Select(item => Process(item);
```

I highly doubt that you need the results as a list, but if you did you could always convert the result to a list via:

```
var L = result.ToList();
```