# for or Parallel.For in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

Can someone suggest where someone is supposed to use the **for** loop instead of **Parallel.For** in .**NET 4.0 Framework**?

I have done small PoC on using for and Parallel.For on a specific long algorithm and result are quite in favour of Parallel.For even in Single Core environment.

Can we simple ignore the **for** loop in .NET 4.0 Framework?

Comment: When you want a loop to run sequentially instead of simultaneously?  For example, if the loop modifies the collection over which it iterates.  Doing that in multiple threads would be... unwise.

Comment: Uh, no.  What you use in each case is determined by your requirements and restrictions for that code.  You cannot say anything is always in programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of Parallel.For](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4635147/109702) or [When to use Parallel.For?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3715850/109702), and that was the [first page](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parallel.for) of the results...

Comment: Thanks slugster for your suggestion. I had already gone through that and after then only I have posted my question as I was really looking some more points as best explained below by Mark in the below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *lots* of factors to consider here:

- is the code inside the loop *written* to support concurrent access? is it thread safe? if not: that's a huge problem
- if all the threads would end up immediately needing didicated / synchronized access to a single resource (such as the UI), then there is nothing to gain from concurrency
- what else is happening on this machine? if this is a web server, it may be better ***not*** for one request to hijack lots of cores
- but conversely, if this is a client-side application, then sure: use lots of cores *and* ideally free up the UI thread ASAP
- is the work CPU bound? IO bound? what? Parallel access to a single disk spindle can make things worse, not better
- threading has overhead; concurrency *increases* the total work done - with the intent of reducing the *elapsed* time
- is it done locally, or on a different server? if so, what is the threading model of that other server?

In most cases, `for` / `foreach` is fine.